# Global perl hash reference asignment

Tags: perl, reference, perl-data-structures

I have a global perl hash, to which i am assign the value from my local reference, I am not sure if that does a copy to the global hash or uses the same reference, but that should be a local memory to the block.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash; 
foreach $a (1..10) {
    my $localref = {"test"=> 1};
    $hash->[$a] = $localref; # does this result in copy?
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note.... you are accessing $hash as an array, not as a hash (`$hash->{$a} = $localref` would be the correct thing to do)

Comment: Your code does not contain any global hashes, or any other global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this should be the global hashref:

```
my $hash;
```

The loop goes trough 1 to 10 creating a local scope hash reference $localref:

```
foreach $a (1..10) {
    my $localref = {"test"=> 1};
```

$localref is now a pointer to the memory address of a hashref containing `{test => 1}`. Try to add a `print` command to see it:

```
    print $localref;
```

You'll notice that the memory address shown changes for each loop run.

```
    $hash->[$a] = $localref; # does this result in copy?
}
```

`$hash->[$a]` is using a variable called *$hash* as an ArrayRef. You should consider renaming it.

Try showing the contents of your "global" $hash after the loop:

```
for (1..10) {
    print $_."\t".$hash->[$_];
}
```

You'll see all your references still alive.

Use Data::Dumper to show the contents:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($hash);
```

Final conclusion:

The memory location storing your HashRefs always stays the same, the contents are never copied, but the reference (address information) is copied. Two references to the same location exist for a short moment between `$hash->[$a] = $localref;` and `}`.

PS: The memory used by `{"test"=> 1}` will be freed as soon as no reference to it exists any longer.

Comment: thank you Sebastian, i tried to print the references, they are the same references. So memory is not freed unless it has last all references, even though it was created in a  different scope.

Comment: That's correct @newguy. This is called `REFCNT` or reference count. Once the `REFCNT` drops to 0, the item is released.

Comment: Yes. A reference variable (like $localref or the $array) is just like a business card holding the address. Throwing it away doesn't bring down the house at this address, you just don't know it's location any longer - but other people (business cards) may still do.

Answer (score 2):

`$hash` is actually an array ref, not a hash ref, and no, the element (`$localref`) you're assigning to the aref is not a copy, because it itself is a reference. To make it a copy, you have to dereference before inserting: `%{ $array->[$a] } = %$localref;`

Comment: yes its a array ref in the above example, i mean in a generic way, in case of a reference. That what i expected, but $localref is a local memory, how does that work

Comment: Because inserting a local (ie. lexical) item into an item of a larger scope as a reference means that the inner variable won't go out of scope until the item in the larger scope does. In your case, the scope is global, so the inner `$localref` doesn't go out of scope until the program exits.